# Character Encoding problem when saving to a file from a TEXT BOX content

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, encoding, character

The problem is with characters Ğ, ğ, Ş, ş

Here is my code:

```
# save file
def save_file():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(defaultextension='.txt', filetypes=[("Text File","*.txt"),
                                        ("HTML File", "*.html"), ("DOC File", "*.doc"),
                                        ("All Files", "*.*")])
    if file is None:
        return
    file_text = text_box.get('1.0', END)

    with open("file_text.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
        outFile.write(file_text)
    file.write(file_text)
    file.close()
# end save as file
```

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mmara\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\risk2.py", line 163, in save_file
    file.write(file_text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: character maps to <undefined>
```

Process finished with exit code 0

When I execute the code and use the SAVE AS button and if the text in the text_box has for example a Ş or ş characters in it I get the above error message.... And file is not saved....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  (In particular, _which_ problem is with characters Ğ, ğ, Ş, ş? Maybe you see Äž, ÄŸ, Åž, ÅŸ instead?)

Comment: @JosefZ My guess would be the characters don't get saved correctly

Comment: tkinter doesn't have a "text box". It helps if you use the proper terminology.

Comment: How do you know it's not saving the data? You say there's a problem but you don't show what the problem is.

Comment: @PetrL. _… characters don't get saved correctly_ is the same vague description as _… problem is with characters …_. A [mcve] is  relevant (and any guess isn't).

Comment: @JosefZ You're Czech, you know it. When č or ř is saved as anything but č or ř

Answer (score 0):

The `file` returned by `filedialog.asksaveasfile` is an opened file handle.  It appears to be opened in a default encoding of `cp1252`.  Instead use `asksaveasfilename` to get the filename and `open` it yourself with `encoding='utf8'` similar to how `outFile` was opened.

Tested example:

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

file_name = asksaveasfilename()

if file_name:
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write('Ğ, ğ, Ş, ş')
```

Comment: Can you expand on the code line necessary to do that. Tried several things but they did not work...

Comment: @MMA Added an example

Comment: Thanks for the response. The SAVE AS code part I gave above is within a long code. The above SAVE AS code is executed by the SAVE AS button. The SAVE AS button action first reads the text_box content which contains text typed by the individual user of the application. Thus it may contain Ş, ş, Ğ, ğ characters (all other alphabetic characters are working with no problem including Ö, ö, Ç, ç, and other common letters etc ). Than the contents of the text_box read is saved on any drive on ones computer as a *.txt, *.doc  etc... file. Thus, "file.write(file_text)" line is necessary.

Comment: @MMA You already have that code.  Integrate my sample.  Read the text box and call `f.write(file_text)`.  I am just demoing that *whatever* you write to the file will work if you open it yourself.

Comment: There is some progress: with the revısed code The code is now executing without error and the file is saved. But when I open *.txt file in wordpad I get Ş as Åž or when I save the file as *.doc file when I open the file with WORD I get again Ş as Åž. Interestingly the file explorer on the file display side shows Ş as Ş.

Comment: Further, when I open *.txt file with NOTEPAD everything is fine. All Ş are Ş and all ş are ş. But WORDPAD and WORD has a problem.

Comment: @MMA Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'`.  Some Windows program perfer UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding to recognize UTF-8.  What you are seeing is UTF-8 misread as CP1252.

Comment: w/ BOM did not work   LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8 w/ BOM

Comment: utf-8-sig   works but same problem with *.doc file. *.txt works with NOTEPAD only.

Comment: utf-8-sig created *.txt file can now be opened with WORDPAD and NOTEPAD. It reads Ş as Ş and ş as ş. But WORD does not work on *.doc file. By the way I am using WORD 365.